# Should I drop and re-create database to save space?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Microsoft SQL Server instance `Instance1` with a database called `Maintenance`, with a table called `TempWorkOrder`. I have another SQL Server instance `Instance2` that has a database called `MaintenanceR1` with a table called `WorkOrder`.

`Instance2` is a linked database on `Instance1`. I want to copy any changed or new records from `Instance2.MaintenanceR1.WorkOrder` to `Instance1.Maintenance.TempWorkOrder` every hour.

I thought about creating a job that deletes all of the records in `Instance1.Maintenance.TempWorkOrder` and repopulates it with `Instance2.MaintenanceR1.WorkOrder` every hour. I am afraid this approach will let the log file get out of control as far as size goes.

Would I be better off dropping the table and re-creating it to keep the log file size reasonable? The table contains about 30,000 rows of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

30,000 rows really shouldnt cause anything to get out of control. If you are really worried about log size, you can truncate instead of delete and bulk load with minimal logging your insert into the table.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1185/minimally-logging-bulk-load-inserts-into-sql-server/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql